# How avoid UNION on count(*) sorting by value?

Tags: mysql, count, union

This query is sorting the results by the value of select count(*). I don't want this to happen. How can I avoid this? I want to show them in the order they are written in the query. Thank you for helping.

This is a piece of query:

```
(select count(*) as num_tweet from [TvPad2-dev].dbo.TWEET where REQUEST_ID = 7 
and CREATION_DATE>'2016-02-14 01:00:00.000' 
and CREATION_DATE<'2016-02-14 01:29:59.999' 
and text like '%arisa%') 

union 

(select count(*) as num_tweet from [TvPad2-dev].dbo.TWEET where REQUEST_ID = 7 
and CREATION_DATE>'2016-02-14 01:30:00.000' 
and CREATION_DATE<'2016-02-14 01:59:59.999' 
and text like '%arisa%')
```

Comment: I am not sure there is any fixed order in that case. However as you are using UNION, MySQL has to go through the results to check for and eliminate duplicates and it will do a sort as part of this. It probably just defaults to ordering by the fields ascending. While I wouldn't rely on it, switching to UNION ALL might solve this (and makes more logical sense for your query I think).

Comment: Are you trying to get counts in half-hour segments? If so there's a much shorter way to go about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UNION ALL will do the trick. If you change UNION to UNION ALL you won't get sorted results.

Answer (score 2):

Use UNION ALL.

```
(select count(*) as num_tweet from [TvPad2-dev].dbo.TWEET where REQUEST_ID = 7 
and CREATION_DATE>'2016-02-14 01:00:00.000' 
and CREATION_DATE<'2016-02-14 01:29:59.999' 
and text like '%arisa%') 

union all

(select count(*) as num_tweet from [TvPad2-dev].dbo.TWEET where REQUEST_ID = 7 
and CREATION_DATE>'2016-02-14 01:30:00.000' 
and CREATION_DATE<'2016-02-14 01:59:59.999' 
and text like '%arisa%')
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try as soon as possible and let you know